# Assign Access to Multiple Sites in Sitecore 7.5

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I have a small question related to granting access to multiple sites in Sitecore 7.5.

Let's say I have a website named as `website_1` and another website named as `website_2` in my Sitecore environment. Now I have created two roles. One role named as `r_website_1` gives access to `website_1` and another role `r_website_2` gives access to `website_2`.

> **In `r_website_1`, only access to `website_1` is granted and access to `website_2` is denied. The same goes for `r_website_2` but for
>   `website_2`.**

Now I want to give read and write access to `user_1` for both websites. What I did was went to `User Manager>user_1>Edit>Member Of` and then assigned both roles.

What I noticed that the `user_1` only gets access to one website. it seems that both roles are countering each another. For example, the denied permission for `website_2` in `r_website_1` is conflicting with allowed permission for `website_2` in `r_website_2`.

May I know what's the fix for this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Vaibhav

Answer (score 1):

`Deny` permission always has priority. You cannot remove by simply adding another role with allow access rights.

Instead of using `deny` you should break the inheritance of chosen access right for the **role1** for **site2** and similarly for the **role2** for **site1**.

Here is a quote from Sitecore Administrator Security Cookbook:

> We recommend that you use inheritance whenever possible to limit the access that roles have to the items in Sitecore. Using inheritance instead of directly denying access rights to items makes it easier to manage the security system.

And you can read about breaking inheritance of access rights in [Assign access rights to a security account](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/security_and_administration/assign_access_rights_to_a_security_account) document.